# Geospatial join in snowflake

Tags: sql, join, location, geospatial, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am looking to do some sort of geospatial join in snowflake. Currently, running this query takes over a day.

I have one table of location data points (~1 billion records), and another table of POI locations (~6k), (both have lat/lon as coordinates).  I want to plot how many data points I am seeing within X meters of a POI.

Can only use snowflake, or any open source program.  Any help is appreciated.

I would like to see a table with the columns below:

POI_id     Radius     Data Points

Comment: Can you post how are you doing it today? E.g. what is the query, both dataset examples etc.

Answer (score 2):

[Haversine Function](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/functions/haversine.html)

the way to do this is via a haversine function within the 'on' clause joining the two tables.

```
select *
from table1 a
inner join table2 b
on haversine(a.lat,a.long,b.lat,b.long) <= 10
;
```

so join if 10km or less as example above

Comment: if the dataset is too big, you can also join on simple grids, like round(lon,2) as lon_r, round(lat,2) as lat_r. Then it's much faster.

Answer (score 0):

Update on the answer, Snowflake now recommends using the [ST_DISTANCE](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/st_distance) function instead:

`ST_DISTANCE ( <geography_or_geometry_expression_1> , <geography_or_geometry_expression_2> )`

So the code would be:

```
select *
from table1 a
inner join table2 b
on st_distance(st_point(a.long, a.lat), st_point(b.long, b.lat)) <= 10*1000
;
```

Also note that this code will duplicate your location points if you have more than 1 Point of Interest within 10km of a location: that location would join to both POIs, creating 2 rows in the output.

Use `select distinct` to solve that.