# Join on nearest geometry in Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, geopandas

I want to join two Snowflake tables based on their X,Y (long, lat) coordinates.

Each row in the two tables is a point, and I would like to join each row in table A to the **nearest** point in table B.

In Python, the GeoPandas module has this, which does exactly what I need: [geopandas.GeoDataFrame.sjoin_nearest](https://geopandas.org/en/v0.13.2/docs/reference/api/geopandas.GeoDataFrame.sjoin_nearest.html)

Is there a way to do this in Snowflake SQL? In this particular case I have (lat, long) points, but the solution should ideally work for any geometry / geography.

Note that this is not the same as joining on points within a certain distance, for which there is the Haversine function as per this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46675559/geospatial-join-in-snowflake).

Answer (score 1):

This might not be the most optimized solution, but it works:

```sql
select a.id, b.id, a.p, b.p, st_distance(a.p, b.p) dist
from random_points a
join random_points b
on a.id != b.id
qualify row_number() over(partition by a.id, b.id order by dist desc) = 1
```

We are doing a cross join, and using `qualify` to only get the closest point on table `b` to each one on table `a`.

Setup:

```sql
create or replace table random_points as 
SELECT row_number() over(order by 1) id
    , ST_POINT(
      (UNIFORM(-180::float, 180, RANDOM())), 
      (UNIFORM(-90::float, 90, RANDOM()))
    ) p
FROM TABLE(GENERATOR(ROWCOUNT => 500));
```